# Can people see if I read their LinkedIn message?

Tags: linkedin, linkedin-messages

Do people I receive messages from on LinkedIn get a "read" receipt after I've opened their message?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Now *Read Receipts Indicators* are available for iOS and Android. When read receipts is turned on, you can see whether your sent messages have been read or not.

**Notes:**

- Read receipts and typing indicators are available initially only on mobile.
- Your read receipts and typing indicators will not be visible to senders of InMails.

For more details see LinkedIn Help page: [Using Read Receipts and Typing Indicators](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/71013/using-read-receipts-and-typing-indicators?lang=en)

Comment: Obsolete content should be removed, specially links that are not working anymore. While I just removed the content from the original revision, the content added in [rev. 2](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/revisions/89965/2) looks to be obsolete. Better to go directly to the linked help article. It was updated 3 months ago, nowadays has two tabs, one for Desktop and another for Mobile.

Answer (score 5):

**Update July 2017**

There is now a "Read" icon in the linked in messaging system, indicating that the message was read and by whom. It currently does now show *when* the message was read.

---

January 2017, I received a dialog after logging in to LinkedIn, that [informed me](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/71013?query=message%20read) that, using a feature called *Read Receipts and Typing Indicators*, users can see when their mail is read and when someone is typing a reply.

LinkedIn notes that

> - Read receipts and typing indicators are available initially only on 
>     mobile.
> - Your read receipts and typing indicators will not be visible to senders of InMails.

Which seems to hint that we can expect this to be enabled on the regular website as well.

The feature can be toggled in settings.

Comment: Better to go directly to the linked help article. It was updated 3 months ago, nowadays has two tabs, one for Desktop and another for Mobile.

Answer (score -1):

Yes there is a way. There's a mini thumbnail of the person's profile pic of the person who read the message. So if it's you that saw a message, they will see a thumbnail underneath their message. If there is no thumbnail it doesn't necessarily mean that a message is unread as some people receive message to their email inbox, too. So it's not 100%.

Answer (score -2):

From my observations in some cases, a little chat head bubble appears when someones read receipts are on. But if they're off which may be able to be disabled it's difficult to tell.